# Lambda Test Tool 3.1 in Rider on Ubuntu: Failed to find type

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, .net-core, aws-lambda

I've recently moved from Windows to Ubuntu and started using Rider as my .NET IDE, now I'm trying to get the AWS .NET Lambda Test Tool to work and followed the readme in the repo carefully but I can't seem to figure out why my setup isn't working.. It's complaining about a the type that can't be found of the method I'm pointing to.

> exe path I'm pointing to: */home/bruno/.dotnet/tools/.store/amazon.lambda.testtool-3.1/0.11.3/amazon.lambda.testtool-3.1/0.11.3/tools/netcoreapp3.1/any/Amazon.Lambda.TestTool.BlazorTester.dll* (which is valid considered Rider)

and I'm pointing to my bin/debug/netcoreapp3.1 from my lambda project root, the readme says just point to your lambda project root, I've tried that too but didn't same to work.

> /home/bruno/Work/tariffinfo-export/src/TariffInfo.Export.Processor.Lambda/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1

I use an additional aws-lambda-tools-defaults-mainqueuehandler.json, which looks like this:

[image]

The error I'm getting is:

> Failed to find type TariffInfo.Export.Processor.Lambda.EventHandler"

EventHandler is my class inside the proj.

Comment: I'm able to reproduce it on the .NET Core 2.1 Test Tool in a different project whilst making use of:
`/home/bruno/.dotnet/tools/.store/amazon.lambda.testtool-2.1/0.11.3/amazon.lambda.testtool-2.1/0.11.3/tools/netcoreapp2.1/any/Amazon.Lambda.TestTool.WebTester21.dll`


I've a slight feeling I'm either doing something wrong or I've overseen that the tool is not supported in the environment I'm trying to make it work on, anyhoo would love to hear if others are facing this issue or what I could do to fix it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolved**

After adding `<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>` to the targeted .csproj